# Check if swatch exists before insert, and if exists insert in next column

Tags: javascript, css, sweetalert

I have a function to insert user generated gradient swatches in to bootstrap columns,but want to check if there is already a swatch, and if so insert in to next column. Also collect the user generated title of it from a sweetalert value, which I cant seem to get outside the alert function.  At the moment it writes the first gradient swatch, then just inserts col-md-4s after that on subsequent entries, with no gradient. The cols have an id of bg-gradient, which is styled for size only.
Code is below if any tips on how to check if a swatch is already there, (and the sweetalert issue to collect the title). Thanks

```
function createSwatch () {
    showdata.textContent = `linear-gradient(to right, ${colorone.value}, ${colortwo.value})`;
    // Set the actual css style value/statement for the gradient
    let gradient = showdata.textContent;
    // Get just the hex values to display/user copy
    let hexValues = `${colorone.value} - ${colortwo.value}`;
    // Select the inputed value/statement to copy
    let range = document.createRange();
    range.selectNode(document.getElementById("showvalue"));
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges(); // clear current selection
    window.getSelection().addRange(range); // to select text
    // Copy the css statement
    document.execCommand("copy");
    window.getSelection().removeAllRanges();// to deselect
    // Name the new watch
    swal("Give Your Swatch a Name:", {
        content: "input",
      })
      .then((value) => {
        swal(`Cool, its called: ${value}`)
    });
    //let swatchValue = swal.value;
    //console.log(swatchValue);
    // Create the swatch elements, starting with the class and id
    let newDiv = document.createElement('div');
    newDiv.classList.add("col-md-3");
    newDiv.setAttribute("id", "bg-gradient");
    // Add the user input to give swatch a title, with the hex values, and edit/delete buttons
    newDiv.innerHTML = `<h5><input type='text' onclick='add_text()' value='Set Title' /></h5><br />${hexValues}`;
    // Conditional statement to check if swatch exists before insertion
    let newSwatch = document.querySelector('.row');
    // FIX THIS BIT
    newSwatch.appendChild(newDiv);
    let swatch = document.getElementById("bg-gradient");
    swatch.style.backgroundImage = gradient;
    //console.log(gradient);
}
```

Also would actually like to display the swatch like the image attached if poss. Thanks[image]

Comment: a gradient is an image so only background or backgroundImage

Comment: Hi yes that's it fixed with backgroundImage, one more thing though, subsequent submissions don't set the background though they do register the new swatches/divs, what is the best way to fix that? Thanks